# How to download files in drive of a google service account

Tags: android, google-drive-api, service-accounts

- I am able to **insert**/upload as well as **list** the files in my google service account using com.google.api.services.drive.**Drive.files().list()**
- But when I use **getDownloadUrl()** to download the file , I get (**Invalid login credentials**) message in external downloader /browser
- or even if I download through my app , I get java.io.**FileNotFoundException** .

Here's my code:

```
public void getDriveService() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, URISyntaxException {
    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
    ArrayList<String> scopes = new ArrayList<String>();
    scopes.add(DriveScopes.DRIVE);
    scopes.add(DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA);
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
            .setServiceAccountId("akh....@smart-spark-13..5.iam.gserviceaccount.com")
            .setServiceAccountScopes(scopes)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(File p12)
            .build();

    com.google.api.services.drive.Drive service = new com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null)
            .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential)
            .build();
    //return service;
    mydrive = service;
    }
```

This might be related to file permissions but I am able to view my file's thumbnail link using getThumbnailUrl() but on downloading through getDownloadUrl() throws an exception ;
where

- thumbnail link is of the form: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/87xKNRudk...xyz
- download url is of the form: https://doc-0s-84-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/pm97hbrcn...xyz

Comment: Found the solution.. File's metacontent can be downloaded using httpsresponse.getContent() ;    
 https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get#examples